# How can I write to a CSV without getting a Unicode Error?

Tags: python, csv, unicode

I've seen many examples of this issue, but haven't yet found a straightforward solution that's worked for me. I still receive the error:

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xad' in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)`

Here's the code I've put together based on similar questions raised on stackoverflow.

```
f = open(out_filepath, 'w')
  writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames, extrasaction='ignore')
  headers = dict([(header, header) for header in fieldnames])
  data = [headers]
  data.extend([row for row in rows]) # add data rows
  for row in data:
    try:
        writer.writerow(row)
    except:
        for value in row.itervalues():
            for s in value:
                try:
                    unicode(s).encode("utf-8")
                except:
                    s = ''
        writer.writerow(row)
  f.close()
```

Here's the updated code that I'm trying that's still giving me errors:

```
for row in data:
    try:
        writer.writerow(row)
    except:
        for key in row:
            value = row[key]
            letterlist = list(value)
            for i in range(len(letterlist)):
                try:
                    letterlist[i].decode('string_escape')
                    letterlist[i].encode('ascii', 'ignore')
                except:
                    print 'Letter excluded from ' +key+' '+ str(letterlist) 
                    letterlist[i] = ''
            value = ''.join(letterlist)
            row[key] = value
        #print row
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: that is latin-1 encoding `u'\xad'.encode("latin-1")`

Comment: If it's latin-1 encoding, how can I fix what I have so that I don't get the error?

Comment: try `writer.writerow([s.encode("utf-8") for s in row])`, is your data unicode?

Comment: I'm still getting a UnicodeEncodeError.

Comment: what does your actual data look like. I can write u`'\xad'` to file using the code above

Comment: I got this error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Here's an example piece of data: "MaczyÅ„ski"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this function to convert unicode to utf8.

```
def ValConvert(val):
  if type(val).__name__ == 'unicode':
    return val.encode('utf8')
  elif type(val).__name__ == 'str':
    return val
  else:
    return str(val)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what has worked for me:

```
f = open('eg.csv', 'w')
s = 'some troublesome string'
f.write(s.decode('string_escape'))
```

and if that doesn't work I do:

```
f.write(s.encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
```

Comment: Are you trying `writer.writerow(row.decode('string_escape'))` and `writer.writerow(row..encode('ascii', 'ignore'))` ?

Comment: I tried that and am getting an error. I edited my post to show you what I have so far.

Comment: Try doing the decoding/encoding as you write, like `writer.writerow(row.decode('string_escape'))`